Traveling to Canada from another country as a greencard holder
I am a greencard holder in the US. Do I need to apply for eTA or visa when I travel to Canada from another country?

Remember that the airline(s) will also check to make sure you are admissible into any transit countries you may have to enter as you travel to Canada.

The requirement for an eTA was removed recently, and you may mind some systems still think you need it. eg, as at a few months ago, United Airlines online check-in system would not let you check-in without one. For the sake of C$7, you may want to get one anyway (that's what I did, to get around United's issue)

No, US citizens and green card holders don't need to apply for ETA no matter the origin.
See the Canadian Immigration Authority:

Travellers who are exempt from the eTA requirement.

U.S. citizens are exempt from the eTA requirement and must carry proper identification such as a valid U.S. passport.
Lawful permanent residents of the United States who hold valid status in the U.S. are exempt from the eTA requirement.

They must carry official proof of status (or an equivalent status document) and a valid passport from their country of nationality (or an equivalent travel document).





Origin of the flight or origin of the person?

No matter the origin of the flight, or the person.

No. A US permanent resident (i.e. green card holder) is exempt from needing a visa or an eTA to enter Canada as a visitor.
See section 190(1)(c) of the Immigration and Refugee Protection Regulations:

190 (1) A foreign national is exempt from the requirement to obtain a
temporary resident visa if they
(c) are a national of the United States or a person who has been
lawfully admitted to the United States for permanent residence.

And section 7.1(3)(b) of the Immigration and Refugee Protection Regulations:

(3) The following persons are exempt from the requirement to obtain an
electronic travel authorization:
(b) a national of the United States or a person who has been lawfully
admitted to the United States for permanent residence;

